# How do make a POST/GET call when using the Tumblr API in C#?

Tags: c#, oauth, tumblr

I'm trying to build a little program that uses Tumblr's API (https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) to fetch and scan a list of recent followers of your blog for spam users (default picture and no blog title), but I can't get any calls to work.

```
namespace FukenSpamms
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

           // string username = new string(args[0]);
           // string password = new string(args[1]);
            
            
            //var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx");
            var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/t:kNyBuCcQK_ON54wQBfzT1Q/followers");
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);`
```

To my understanding, this should work, though I think I also need to implement OAuth in some way (Can't find any modern examples).

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What HTTP status code do you get in response?

Comment: The endpoint you're trying to use requires OAuth authentication. Have you created app in tumblr? There doesn't seem anything unique about how tumblr does OAuth2, so there's a lot of internet resources about how to do that.